# Display best match first

Tags: php, preg-match

```html
$input = "work is hard";   

if(preg_match(  "/(work|shift|useful)/i",$input)){
$match[]= "this is not better match";
}

if(preg_match(  "/(how|work|can|be|really|really|hard)/i",$input)){
$match[]= "this is better match";   // i want this match to appear first.
}
```

if i have multiple preg_match and one has more words that match the input, how can i make it so that it displays the one with the most matches. now, it just displays it in order. this is how it outputs

```html
<?php
if(!empty($match)) {
foreach ($match as $r) {
    echo "<li>$r</li>\n";
 
}
}
?>
```

Comment: What do you understand by "best match"? And exact match? Most words matched?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$input = "work is hard";            
$reg = array( "First match"=>"/(work|shift|useful)/i","second match"=>"/(how|work|can|be|really|really|hard)/i");
foreach($reg as $index=>$val){
    $count[] = preg_match_all($val,$input);
}
foreach($count as $i){
    $max = max($count);
    $key = array_search($max,$count); 
    $allKeys = array_keys($reg);
    echo "The Best Match is:  ".$allKeys[$key]."<br>"; 
    $del = array_search($max,$count);
    unset($count[$del]);
}
```

Comment: What if i wanted to display something if it has a better match. in my case i want to display a specific text when the input is matching one of them. for `work shift useful` display a specific text and same for other matches. and also do you know how to make second `Best match is` and so on

Comment: Is there a way to make this code faster, when i plugged in my data into the array it takes forever to load. Thanks by the way, this really helped

Comment: wats the length of the array??

Comment: about 100 right now(commas), it might increase as time pass

Answer (score 0):

split the input string into an array of words and use `array_intersect` with your sets of words of interest and compare the lengths of the resulting arrays to decide the best match.